# Can't change the value of self

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the following error from Passenger when trying to run a Rails app in production:

```
self = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

which comes from my `user.rb` model.  Any ideas on why this is occuring?  The full module is as follows:

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

and it's purpose is to set a secure token when the user requests a password reset, which comes from the following:

```
def send_password_reset #From 274
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```

Any ideas?  I can't see any syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, `self` gives you access to the current object and cannot be set. In this case, `self` refers to the current instance of the `User` model. It looks like you just want to set the password_reset_token column, so:

```
def generate_token(column_name)
  write_attribute column_name, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```